# Cucumber not running selenium Code

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-cpp

When I try to run my code, it only shows cucumber skeleton. I use a JUnit runner class as JUnit test suite.

Code is below for all three classes.

**Feature is :**

```
Feature: Check addition in Google calculator

   In order to verify that google calculator work correctly
   As a user of google
   I should be able to get correct addition result
@Runme
   Scenario: Addition
   Given I open google
   When I enter "2+2" in search textbox
   Then I should get result as "4"
```

**Selenium Class :**

```
package cucumberTest;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SeleniumTest {
    private SeleniumTest()
    {


    }
        private static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static void seleniumTest() {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //Put a Implicit wait, this means that any search for elements on the page could take the time the implicit wait is set for before throwing exception

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Launch the Online Store Website

        driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");

        // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'account'(My Account) 

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/a")).click();

        // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'log' (Username)

        // Enter Username on the element found by above desc.

        driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("testuser_1"); 

        // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'pwd' (Password)

        // Enter Password on the element found by the above desc.

        driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("Test@123");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element 

        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

        // Print a Log In message to the screen

        System.out.println("Login Successfully");

        // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'account_logout' (Log Out)

        driver.findElement (By.xpath(".//*[@id='account_logout']/a")).click();

        // Print a Log In message to the screen

        System.out.println("LogOut Successfully");

        // Close the driver

        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

**JUnit Class:**

```
package cucumberTest;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
//@CucumberOptions(
    //  features = "Feature/googleCalc.feature"
        ////,glue={"stepDefinition"}
    //  )
@CucumberOptions(

features = {"Feature/googleCalc.feature"},glue={"stepDefinition"},

plugin = {"pretty"},

tags = {"@Runme"}

)

public class TestRunner {

}
```

**Step Definitions :**

```
package stepDefination;


import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import cucumberTest.SeleniumTest;

public class googleCalcStepDefinition {

    @Given("^I open google$")
    public void i_open_google() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
      SeleniumTest.seleniumTest();
    }

    @When("^I enter \"(.*?)\" in search textbox$")
    public void i_enter_in_search_textbox(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        SeleniumTest.seleniumTest();
    }

    @Then("^I should get result as \"(.*?)\"$")
    public void i_should_get_result_as(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        SeleniumTest.seleniumTest();
    }

}
```

**Output shown is :**

```
Feature: Check addition in Google calculator

   In order to verify that google calculator work correctly
   As a user of google
   I should be able to get correct addition result

  @Runme
  Scenario: Addition                     [90m# Feature/googleCalc.feature:7[0m
    [33mGiven [0m[33mI open google[0m
    [33mWhen [0m[33mI enter "2+2" in search textbox[0m
    [33mThen [0m[33mI should get result as "4"[0m

1 Scenarios ([33m1 undefined[0m)
3 Steps ([33m3 undefined[0m)
0m0.000s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^I open google$")
public void i_open_google() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^I enter \"(.*?)\" in search textbox$")
public void i_enter_in_search_textbox(String arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^I should get result as \"(.*?)\"$")
public void i_should_get_result_as(String arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Comment: Your gluecode should be stepDefination instead of stepDefinition (if the package/folder names are correct in your post).

Comment: you are rite i did same and its works post this answer so that i can mark you answer correct :-)

Comment: @fahad You may also answer your own question.

Comment: posted are you facing same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason it was not executing because i added Selenium test class and Junit runner class in Package cucumberTest; and skeleton was in package stepDefination; so what i did was i moved skeleton to pacakge cucumberTest; where junit runner and selenium classes are it resolved the issue for . Issue was occuring because when you place Junit class in package it will search for skeleton in that package but if you add JUnit runner class in source folder then it will be able to find the page under src folder